# Moved website from http to https. also submitted on webmaster

Tags: http, https, google-search-console

I have moved my website from http to https. I also submitted it on webmaster.

Now it is showing on webmaster tools like

```
http://same.com
https://same.com
```

Do I need to remove previous submission from webmaster or should I keep it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read google support [Document here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en)

Read the section **URL changes from HTTP to HTTPS**

Also read [this thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console)  for more explanation

Comment: now all my pages is just on https, now what should i do bcz it is saying this (So if you have pages in both protocols, you must have a separate Search Console property for each one)

Comment: You should also read this [thread here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console)

Comment: Glad it helped :)